# Python Singleton using decorator

Tags: python, singleton, decorator, python-decorators

How is the below decorator make `Database` a singleton?

The way I am understanding it is that the `@singleton` decorator makes the `Database` class to a function that returns a `Database` object. However, since it's now acting like a function, when the function call ends, function variables should be dead (e.g. `instances` variable).

The weird part is that when I call this function the second time, it seems like the `instance` variable is still alive and store the previous information, even `id` is the same. How is this happening? Can someone please help me understand this?

Thank you in advance

```py
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal instances
        print(instances, id(instances))
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

    return get_instance

@singleton
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Loading database')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db1 = Database() # first call.
    db2 = Database() # second call. why is this returning the same id?
```

Output

```
{} 4011784
Loading database
{<class '__main__.Database'>: <__main__.Database object at 0x0577C148>} 4011784
```

Comment: The keyword here is [closure](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several concepts which together make this possible. Let's take a look at your current code:

```
@singleton
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Loading database')
```

The above code can be translated to the following code. The `@` syntax is the short form of:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Loading database')

print(Database)
Database = singleton(Database) # manually decorated
print(Database)
```

The class declaration itself is stored to the variable named `Database`. Afterwards, the variable is replaced with the result of the `singleton` function call (which is the `get_instance` function). This means, whenever you create a new instance of `Database` actually `get_instance` is now called.

```
<class '__main__.Database'>
<function singleton.<locals>.get_instance at 0x7f8e82738310>
```

Now let's take a look at the `singleton` function:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal instances # nonlocal is not required here!
        print(instances, id(instances))
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

    return get_instance
```

The `singleton` function declares a local `instances` variable which belongs to the scope of the `singleton` function. On each call to `singleton` a newly independent `get_instance` function (a so-called closure) is created. According to the [LEGB rule](https://medium.com/pragmatech/what-is-the-legb-rule-in-python-9c05967d9108), the variables of the enclosing scope are "*inherit*" (this is technically not correct, but simplifies the explanation) to the closure.  This means, that `instances` will stay the same object for every call to a specific `get_instance` function.

Now let's summarize. As on each call of `Database()` actually `get_instance` is called, and as `instances` stays the same for each call to this specific `get_instance` function, we can achieve the effect, that the class will be created only once and that the same object will be returned for every succeeding call.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is insane! Not only did you understand my question precisely but also gave such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question? Is this a thread-safe Singleton design?

Comment: @idontknoooo It is not thread-safe.

Comment: Nice but has one problem. `singleton()` returns function not type. Then `isinstance(A(), A)` fails.